# How to get a return value?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript is there any way of stopping a function from carrying out an action but still get its return value? I would like to obtain the currentPosition of a game piece on a game board. What would be the best way to do this?

Here is some of my code:

```
let pieceOne = document.getElementById('piece-one');
let pieceTwo = document.getElementById('piece-two');
let squares = document.getElementsByClassName('board-square');
let currentPosition1 = 0;
let currentPosition2 = 0;
const board = [
    'recharge',
    'city-garden',
    'earthship',
    'hydroponics',
    'ev-car',
    'greenway',
    'cycle-path',
    'greenspace',
    'hydroelectric',
    'solar-farm',
    'community-work',
    'habitat-survey'
];

function movePiece() {
    let diceRoll = rollDice();
    if (currentPlayer === 'player1') {
        currentPosition1 += diceRoll;
        if (currentPosition1 >= board.length) {
            currentPosition1 -= board.length;
        }
        let currentSquare = squares[currentPosition1];
        currentSquare.appendChild(pieceOne);
        currentPlayer = players[1];
    } else {
        currentPosition2 += diceRoll;
        if (currentPosition2 >= board.length) {
            currentPosition2 -= board.length;
        }
        let currentSquare = squares[currentPosition2];
        currentSquare.appendChild(pieceTwo);
        currentPlayer = players[0];
    } if (currentPlayer = players[1]) {
        return currentPosition1;
    } else {
        return currentPosition2;
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's possible but I would like to return the values without the dice rolling or the pieces moving.

Comment: I don't get it. Why can't you just access the variables without calling the function?

Comment: You have a bug in your `if (currentPlayer = players[1]) {` line.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to accomplish.  Can you demonstrate what isn't working as expected?

Comment: It sounds like you should perhaps separate some duties, if you don't want a particular function to perform a particular action.

Comment: The variables are set outside the function but then change in the function, when i try to access them i am getting the initial set values. is there a way to access them outside the function? silly question maybe, im very new to this.

Comment: @NovaBrownie: *"when i try to access them i am getting the initial set values"* - Where are you doing this in the code shown?  Nothing in the code shown ever invokes the function and nowhere are these variables used outside of the function.  *"is there a way to access them outside the function?"* - Yes, since they're declared outside the function you can access them anywhere in that scope.  Instead of vaguely describing what you think the problem is in some other code that you're not showing us, please update the question to a [mcve] which specifically demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Assuming you meant your function `movePiece()`, what action do you not want executed? Why include it in the function if you don't want it to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define position as a var giving it global scope.  separate the movePosition() from
getPosition(). the trick here is making position global.  let will define the variable within its scope.  Of course, you don't need a function to get position

```js
var position;
movePiece();
console.log(getPosition())
console.log(position);

function movePiece() {
  position = 5;

}

function getPosition() {
  return position;
}
```

Comment: This will work with `let` as well